# PHPStorm: How to setup running terminal commands instead of trying open it

Tags: laravel, configuration, composer-php, phpstorm, laravel-artisan

lately I start to learning Laravel using PHPStorm.

Anyway I set up composer and all that stuff, but still have problem with one very annoying issue.

Every time I type "composer update" or something similar that need to fire few commands "from under the hood" I receive popup saying:
"Cannot find file" "/Application/.../optimize" - as an example of 
php artisan optimize

It's the same for all commands that's in composer.json file:

```
(...)
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
(...)
```

Which I need to run by myself.
[image: Cannot find file php artisan optimize] 
And funny thing - when I type "php artisan optimize" I get (before I get massages as above): 
[image: Register New File Type Association]

Please help me to set PHPStorm working correctly.

Comment: follow instructions here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/09/command-line-tools-based-on-symfony-console-doctrine-laravel-in-phpstorm/

Comment: I've tried that in previous project and it solve only the second bit of my post.

Comment: you can create a composer alias following the same steps

Comment: After I add composer and artisan to command tool it won't change working of composer but artisan start working that way: Cannot run program "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-learning-3/artisan" (in directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-learning-3/laravel"): error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: My bad - I forget to type php before artisan. But anyway - it change nothing. Still popups from above appears.

Comment: how do you run the command? after adding it you don't need to type `php`, just type `artisan` or `composer`

Comment: artisan as it's actually working - once I configured it that on PHPStorm Command Line it was no need to add "php" prefix. Now it need to have it always (PHPStorm -> Command Line and Terminal). Composer is configured via OS PATH so I always type just "composer". I believe that on OS Terminal it will be working great but even then (when I'm in project folder) PHPStorm "takes control" and popup these alerts.