# PHPStorm: disable terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, phpstorm, osx-elcapitan

some time ago I had similar issue and still have problems with it.

Link to old topic: [PHPStorm: How to setup running terminal commands instead of trying open it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504649/phpstorm-how-to-setup-running-terminal-commands-instead-of-trying-open-it)

Anyway I decide to totally get rid of Terminal in PHPStorm as it's far away of how it should work - I've tried to set it up on few machines - always with same result. Bunch of errors.

But...

Even when I go to preferences and disable the Terminal plugin and try to run the command in my normal Terminal (OS X) it just try to execute it in PHPStorm, of course - with errors.

I've tried to run terminal commands even when PHPStorm is closed and... it starts automatically when I do it.

P.S. It's totally different script then laravel (from the link above) but also composer based script. I have similar alerts as in attached topics.

Now I have PHPStorm 10, back then I had 9.

I know that these commands should work perfect on normal Terminal.

Thanks for all your help!